# How to calculate this complex number expression

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I calculate this term?

$|(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)^{15}|$

I've started by transforming in into polar form:

$|{e^{i(\frac{11}{6}\pi)}}^{15}|$

How do I go on from here?

Comment: Abraham de Moivre might help you here.

Comment: the answer should be $$-i$$ and $$ |-i|=1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You're right, but it's even easier to calculate it as $\left|\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac12i\right|^{15}$...

Comment: ok that may be that is easier in this case

Comment: By the way, ${a^b}^c$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ which is not equal to $(a^b)^c$. You want $$\left|\left(e^{i(\frac{11}{6}\pi)}\right)^{15}\right|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the polar form for this one.

Remember:

$$|z^n| = |z|^n$$
for any integer $n$ and complex number $z$!

Answer (score 0):

As @5xum stated, your calculation method is inefficient. However, it is still a valid way to do so.

Continuing from your progress, I think you meant

$$|{e^{i(\frac{11}{6}\pi)\cdot 15}}|=|{e^{i(\frac{55}{2}\pi)}}|=^*|{e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{2})}}|=|-i|=?$$

where $(*)$ follows from the fact that $e^{i\theta}$ is $2\pi-$periodic.